# How to join 2 lists in Java-8 such that element at same indexes from the 2 list come together in the resultant list

Tags: java, list, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have 2 lists `codeList` and `nameList` both having `String` elements.

```java
    codeList = ["1", "2", "3"];
    nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
```

I want to combine these in such a way that the elements on same index come together in resultant `String` separated with `|`:

```java
"1{One} | 2{Two} | 3{Three}"
```

Is there any way of directly getting the resultant list or String from the 2 list itself using Java 8

I am able to achieve this by using a Map but not list.

Comment: Is the final thing a list?

Comment: What is this `[ "1{One}" | "2{Two}" | "3{Three}" ]` list or String, if list this is not possible!

Comment: @Andronicus: yes I was trying a list,

Comment: @YCF_L I think String will work

Comment: Then what do you want? You're telling every person a different thing...

Comment: @Andronicus: I was trying with to get a List but after reading the replies, I think String was a better option, list can be made out of the String with | being used to split it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `IntStream` with indices of those lists:

```
IntStream.range(0, codeList.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> codeList.get(i) + "{" + nameList.get(i) + "}")
    .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

Comment: would compile without a `mapToObj`

Comment: @Naman you're right, thank you!